# Memory leaks in c++ program

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

My problem is a memory leak somewhere in the code. I can't find it... I used valgrid and it gave information that memory leaks appers when im using method "add_connection". I thought that at the end of add_connection I should delete memory for newNode but then program crushes.

BTW. I can't use std::vector and stuff like this. Code must be really basic. Its requirement ;/

list_graph.h

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node{
int value;
int weight;
Node* next;
};


class List_graph
{
    static const int  MAX_SIZE =1000;
    Node* get_adj_list_node(int dest,Node * head,int weight);
    int Node_number=0;
public:

    Node** head;

    List_graph();
    ~List_graph();
    void add_connection(int source, int target, int weight);
};
```

list_graph.cpp

```
#include "../inc/list_graph.h"

Node*  List_graph::get_adj_list_node(int dest,Node * head,int weight)
{
    Node * new_node = new Node;
    new_node->value=dest;
    new_node->weight=weight;
    new_node->next = head;

    return new_node;
    delete [] new_node;
}


List_graph::List_graph()
{
    head = new Node *[MAX_SIZE]();
    for(int i =0; i<MAX_SIZE;i++)
    {
        head[i]=nullptr;
    }
}

List_graph::~List_graph()
{

    for(int i =0; i<MAX_SIZE;i++)
    {
      delete [] head[i];
    }
    delete [] head;
}

void List_graph::add_connection(int source, int target, int weight)
{
        Node* newNode = get_adj_list_node(target, head[source],weight);
        head[source] = newNode;
        Node_number++;
}
```

Comment: Note: You call `delete` on every element in `head` regardless of if it's `nullptr` or not. You must step over each `nullptr` value. Do not `delete` them.

Comment: @tadman Standard practise. If the professor thinks about the issue at all he probably thinks I had to suffer so there's no reason they shouldn't either.

Comment: @tadman deleting `nullptr` is perfectly OK.

Comment: I see no memory leak in this code. That's doesn't mean you don;t have any, just that you haven't posted the code that causes the memory leak. Just because vagrind says that the leak originates in add_connetction doesn't mean that code causes the leak, just that the leaked memory was allocated there.

Comment: @john Is `delete nullptr` behaviour documented anywhere? Couldn't find it [in the docs for `delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete).

Comment: It's possible that `add_connection` replaces an existing entry in `head` with another allocation and in so doing loses track of the previous entry, causing a leak.

Comment: @tadman Sounds very likely

Comment: @tadman second last paragraph of the section 'Explanation' in the document you linked. Basically delete nullptr is a no-op.

Comment: You realize you have `delete [] new_node;` immediately *after* `return new_node;` in `List_graph::get_adj_list_node`?

Comment: @tadman Is there any option to repair it?

Comment: @john Ah! "If expression evaluates to a null pointer value, no destructors are called, and the deallocation function is not called." as of C++14. Thanks. Guess I'm used to an older more explodey C++ standard.

Comment: You need to `delete` the old entry before replacing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in this code:

```
void List_graph::add_connection(int source, int target, int weight)
{
        Node* newNode = get_adj_list_node(target, head[source],weight);
        head[source] = newNode;
        Node_number++;
}
```

Note if `head[source]` is already populated then you stomp that pointer, losing it forever, and leak allocations.

The fix is to `delete` it first:

```
void List_graph::add_connection(int source, int target, int weight)
{
        Node* newNode = get_adj_list_node(target, head[source],weight);
        delete head[source];
        head[source] = newNode;
        Node_number++;
}
```

Now in your other code:

```
Node*  List_graph::get_adj_list_node(int dest,Node * head,int weight)
{
    // ...
    return new_node;
    delete [] new_node;
}
```

The `delete` line *never runs*, and a good thing too because you'd sabotage the allocation you just made, and it's also the wrong type of `delete` to use.

Comment: Unfortunately, pointers being what they are, there's no guarantee this fix won't cause problems elsewhere in the code. Nothing wrong with the answer, just pointing out to the OP that it may not be the fix they are hoping for.

Comment: @john One bandage at a time and we might plug all the leaks.

Comment: Are you sure the `head[source] = newNode;` is the problem?  From the code it appears that `head[i]` is a linked list and at the point at which `head[source] = newNode;` executes `newNode->next` already points to the current value of `head[source]` -- so that shouldn't be a leak.  Unless I've misread something.

Comment: @G.M. This is some kind of array/linked list thing and it's in a shape that's very unfamiliar so I'm just trying my best here. I don't think we're seeing all the code so there could be other issues. When I see `head` in a linked list I do not expect to see an array.

Comment: @tadman Your solution works for me.  Thank you so much! I know that this implementation of linked list is very weird but like I said its requirement... When i asked teacher why can't we use std::vector and any other goods of C++ he said "First you have to do your own std::vector implementation to understand whats inside... I can't agree with him its the best idea because later i'll have to undo all what i learned :D Anyway thanks :)

Comment: Great to hear it worked. There's nothing wrong with learning about the fundamentals of how C++ works, the [Bjarne book](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) goes into great detail, but it also approaches it from a theoretical level before forcing you down into the dirty details. The bottom-up approach is like learning how to drive by forcing you to build a car from junk parts first, having zero idea of how a car is supposed to be driven.